# Object is possibly 'undefined' in ternary operation

Tags: typescript

I have this bit of code:

```
const newProps = {
    onClick: props.onSelect ? () => props.onSelect(choice.value) : undefined,
}
```

Which in TypeScript will give me the error `Object is possibly 'undefined'`.

I thought TypeScript was smart about this and would understand that at this point, props.onSelect can't be undefined. I know about the `!` operator, but I'd like to know why this isn't working.

Comment: This does not make any sense.  You are defining a `const props` and inside the definition checking to see if `props.onSelect` is truthy - it's always going to be undefined.

Comment: Yes, I simplified real code I have and wasn't careful enough. That's fixed now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the usage of `props.onSelect` is in another function, the arrow function you are defining after the `?`. This means the compiler cannot guarantee that `props.onSelect` is not undefined at the time of the call:

Ex:

```
propsOther.onSelect = undefined;
props.onClick();
```

You need to check `onSelect` within the arrow function as well:

```
const props = {
    onClick: propsOther.onSelect ? () => propsOther.onSelect && propsOther.onSelect(choice.value) : undefined,
}
```

**Note**: I assumed you simplified and that there are actually 2 prop objects, because otherwise your code would not compile.

Comment: Yes, I simplified. Thank you for that answer, that actually makes a ton of sense! Can't believe I didn't realize this myself...